# FlexSlider Not Resizing

Tags: flexslider

When I resize my window, Flexslider does not resize. [You can see my working code here](https://codepen.io/P013370/full/YxjVmE).

I am following [FlexSlider's example](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/index.html), and have reduced all possible variables.

```html
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/500x300" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/500x300" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/500x300" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/500x300" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it's an issue with [version 2.6.4 of FlexSlider](https://github.com/woocommerce/FlexSlider/issues/1665). In the meantime, I just used version 2.6.3

Comment: Thanks, you are correct.  I couldn't figure out why it worked OK on one site and not on another. I thought it was down to using background images in the slides vs foreground images. Reverting to 2.6.3 fixed it for me.